# SQL Server 2012 Concatenating Strings from Multiple Rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, string-concatenation

[Edit] Due to time constraints I gave up on using a CTE and created a function that returns the concatenated string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetCategoryNamesAsString
(
    @lawID INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @categoryNames NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @categoryNames = ''

    DECLARE @categoryID INT

    DECLARE CUR CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR 
        SELECT t1.LawCategoryID FROM [GWS].[dbo].[GWSMasterLawsLawCategories] t1 WHERE t1.LawID = @lawID
    OPEN CUR

    FETCH FROM CUR INTO @categoryID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @categoryNames = @categoryNames + (SELECT t2.Name
                                                        FROM [GWS].[dbo].GWSMasterLawCategories t2
                                                        WHERE t2.LawCategoryID = @categoryID) + ', '
        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @categoryID
    END
    CLOSE CUR
    DEALLOCATE CUR

    RETURN @categoryNames

END
GO
```

This does the job but I don't really like it. If anyone has a better solution I'd love to know.

[End edit]

I have seen several questions the deal roughly with the same topic but none cover the inclusion of null values.

I am writing a query that should return the full contents of one table with a couple of columns added with relevant data from other tables. These columns can include 0 - n values.

Null values need to be stored as an empty string and sets that do have the extra data should display it separated by commas.

Some approaches delivered all the names strung together, some only returned the values separately, some no values at all and, most often, the recursion went to deep (which means I fouled up as the dataset is small).

This is my current approach:

```
DECLARE @categoryNames NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @categoryNames = '';

WITH sources (sourcesLawSourceID, sourcesName) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [LawSourceID], [name]
    FROM [GWS].[dbo].[GWSMasterLawSources]
),
categories AS(
    SELECT GWSCategories.LawCategoryID AS categoryID, GWSLawCategories.LawID AS lawID,
    categoryNames = @categoryNames 
    --CAST(LEFT( GWSCategories.name, CHARINDEX(',', GWSCategories.name + ',') -1)  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) categoryName,
    --STUFF(GWSCategories.name, 1, CHARINDEX(',', GWSCategories.name + ','), '') categoryNames
    FROM [GWS].[dbo].[GWSMasterLawCategories] GWSCategories
    JOIN [GWS].[dbo].[GWSMasterLawsLawCategories] GWSLawCategories
    ON GWSCategories.LawCategoryID = GWSLawCategories.LawCategoryID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT categories.categoryID, categories.lawID, 
    CAST(LEFT( @categoryNames, CHARINDEX(',', @categoryNames + ',') -1)  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + GWSCategories.Name
    FROM categories
    JOIN [GWS].[dbo].[GWSMasterLawCategories] GWSCategories
    ON categories.categoryID = GWSCategories.LawCategoryID
    WHERE @categoryNames > ''
)
SELECT DISTINCT GWSMaster.[LawID]
      ,[Name]

      ,sources.sourcesName LawSourceName
      ,(SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(categories.CategoryNames))
      FROM categories
      FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')) Categories

  FROM [GWS].[dbo].[GWSMasterLaws] GWSMaster
  JOIN sources
  ON sources.sourcesLawSourceID = GWSMaster.LawSourceID
  JOIN categories
  ON categories.lawID = GWSMaster.LawID
```

This leaves the category name field completely empty.

If I can give any more information or I have missed a question that answers my problem please let me know.